# How to trigger on_pre_enter event every time a screen is opened during the same run?

Tags: python, kivy, pymongo

So I am making a notes app as a part of a bigger app. What I want is that every time before the user enters the screen, all the existing notes will be fetched from MongoDB and displayed.

Initially, I tried it with just a on_pre_enter event but then every time the I went to a different screen and came back, the last note from the database got written again on top of the existing labels.

So, then I added a on_pre_leave function but now what happens is that the first time, notes get displayed. But if you leave and come back, the whole screen is empty.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Current code:

```
class Reminders(Screen):
    collection = db['Notes']

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        records = self.collection.find({})
        for record in records:
            existing_lbl = Label(text=record['Note'],
                             size_hint=(0.2, None), text_size=(self.width, None))
            self.ids.layout.add_widget(existing_lbl)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.ids.layout.clear_widgets()

    def add_note(self):
        sm.switch_to(screens[6], direction='left')

    def go_back(self):
        sm.switch_to(screens[0], direction='right')
```

.kv file:

```
< Reminders >:
    name: 'Reminders'
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Notes"
            color: (0, 0.702, 0, 1)
            font_size: 50
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'top': 1}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2

        Button:
            size_hint: 0.07, 0.07
            background_normal: 'plus.png'
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.78,'top': 0.94}
            on_release: root.add_note()

        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 0.96, 0.6
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.02, 'top': 0.7}
            StackLayout:
                id: layout
                orientation: 'tb-lr'

        SmoothButton:
            text: "Back"
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.8, 'top': 0.15}
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.05
            on_release: root.go_back()
```

Comment: can you print the records to see if the problem is in the data I mean is not empty

Comment: no the data set is not empty for sure because the first time you enter the screen during a run, all the notes do get displayed. I ran a print statement just to be sure and the data is all there. The issue is with the displaying